# Yii CGridView Pager generate link wrong?

Tags: gridview, yii, pager

I have a simple search form (site/search.php) to send search string to controller and show search result if available. I'm using CGridView to show data.
*UPDATE* Here is my view (site/search.php) file:

```
     <form name="quickSearchForm" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("site/search"); ?>" method="POST">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              <input type="search" name="searchText" id="searchText" value="<?php echo $searchText; ?>"/>
              <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="search"/>
                    <a href="#">Advanced</a>
           </div>
     </form>


<?php 
   if (!empty(itemList)) {
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'task-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$itemList,
            'pager'=>array(
                'header'         => '',
                'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;',
                'prevPageLabel'  => '&lt;',
                'nextPageLabel'  => '&gt;',
                'lastPageLabel'  => '&gt;&gt;',
            ),
            'template'=>'{pager}{items}{pager}',
            'columns'=>array(
                array(
                    'name'  => 'name',
                    'value' => '$data->name',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'date',
                    'value' => 'date("d/m/Y",strtotime($data->date) )',   
                ),
             ),
        ),);
     } //end if
?>
```

At controller, I'm using $searchText to get data with CActiveDataProvider then render back to search.php.

```
  <?php       
        $this->render($view = "search", array(
            'searchText'    => $searchText,
            'itemList'       => $itemListBySearch,
            'taskResult'    => $tasks,

        ));
```

*END UPDATE*

My problem is $itemList has many item, GridView will paginate. But, I click on button page [2], browser direct to `r=site/search&page=2` and itemList lost!

May I use ajax instead direct to `r=site/search&page=2`???

Comment: what does your search action look like? no need of the entire code, just the render code

Comment: ok, one more thing, how do your files look like? in which file(view) is the search form? in which view(file) is the grid?

Comment: Oh, gridView and search form are in one file `site/search.php` (update above)

Comment: use @MadAnd's suggested `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(array('site/search'), 'get'); ?>`, gridView running is very good. It's doesn't direct to `site/index` when click on paging button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii pager's default implementation preserves all **GET** values from the request, but your search form is using **POST**, so search term aren't included in pagination links. Try to change form method to GET and you'll get desired behavior:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(array('site/search'), 'get'); ?>
```

**PS**: IMHO search forms should always use **GET** method to send search options, because it provides ability to copy URL which holds all search terms, and then send it to someone else (for example to developers) or save it for further reproduction of the same request.

Comment: Yep, I know a popular search page should use **GET** method, but when use **GET** method, after click on submit button, my page direct to `r=site/index&searchText=string_to_searching`, while that, my search action is `r=site/search`. How to make it doesn't direct to `site/index` ?

Comment: Thank you so much! When i use `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(array('site/search'), 'get'); ?>`, it works very good!